# OpenGL: In VMware (debian x64), glxgears works - but not other OpenGL programs

Tags: opengl, vmware, freeglut, glx

After installing debian in VMware and installing all librarys required to run OpenGL applications with freeglut, I used `glxgears` to make sure everything works fine.

```
# glxgears
3426 frames in 5.0 seconds = 685.171 FPS
3562 frames in 5.0 seconds = 712.339 FPS
...
XI0:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
after 33172 requests (33170 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

`glxgears` seems to be running fine. It displays the gears roatating in a window even though the above error appears after clicking on "Close" on the glxgears window frame.

But when I attempt to execute a simple OpenGL program using freeglut3, I get the following result:

```
# ./program
X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request: 155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 34 ()
Serial number of failed request: 36
Current serial number in output stream: 35
```

A program which works using all the same files and libraries on a non-virtual machine, not available for me at home.

How can I resolve this issue? Is this a common problem with running OpenGL programs on virtual machines?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cryptic way of your GLX server telling you: ***it has never heard of `glXCreateContextAttribsARB`*** (GLX OpCode 34). In other words, your system does not support [`GLX_ARB_create_context`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt). The best way to explain why this is, would be to run something like `glxinfo -v` and add the output to your question.

It is possible to create a working context without this extension on your system as `glxgears` is clearly demonstrating. I have to imagine that freeglut3 should be smart enough not to use the extension if you do not request anything fancy from it (*e.g.* do not ask for a core profile context or a specific major/minor version). If it is not, then you will have to find a more sophisticated GLX implementation or use a different framework.